# Rails undefined method `update_attributes' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get a error when trying to update atributtes.

```
   C:\Rails\App>rake reklamer:iqmedier
    (in C:/Rails/App)
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `update_attributes' for []:Array
    C:/Rails/App/lib/tasks/statistik.rake:23:in `block (2 levels) in
     <top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
    C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Here is some part of my rake task:

```
  @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')[-2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }

  @existing = Reklamer.find(:all, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0]})
  if @existing.nil?
      Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2], :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
  else
    @existing.update_attributes(:unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are finding all, and you can't update an array, so you have two options:

(1) Update all the matching Reklamer objects:

```
@existing = Reklamer.find(:all, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0]})
  if @existing.empty?
      Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2], :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
  else
    @existing.each{ |e| e.update_attributes(:unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8]) }
  end
```

(2) Update only a single instance of the Reklamer object:

```
@existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0]})
  if @existing.nil?
      Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2], :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
  else
    @existing.update_attributes(:unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
  end
```

Comment: How do I prevent duplicates. Example one column time is: 2011-02-15 23:53:28 and it creates a new with time:2011-02-15 00:00:00. How to prevent that?

Comment: That makes sense. Those are different times, so comparing them will not result in equality. That's different from the issue you have here though, so I would recommend creating a new question thread with details surrounding what you are trying to accomplish. Don't forget to mark this question as accepted though :)

Comment: I dont understand why it is creating a 100% duplicate now? The time is the same I thougt I was checking for a duplicate

Comment: The two times you posted are different '2011-02-15 23:53:28' is not equivalent to '2011-02-15 00:00:00'. Although they are on the same day, they are 23 hours 53 minutes and 28 second apart. That's almost an entire day difference.

Comment: I have tested now and it is creating a 100% replica. The times are 2011-02-15 00:00:00 and 2011-02-15 00:00:00

Comment: Is @stats[0] a String, a DateTime, a Time or a Date object? And are you using the first code example or the second one? Have you changed your if condition to @existing.empty? if you are using the first one?

Comment: I would recommend creating another question so that you can have your problem addressed properly. The comments are not the best way to handle this. You'll be able to specify the code you are using and your expected behavior in a better format.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord's `#find(:all, ...)` returns an array of records, not a single record. If you wanted to update all of the matching records, you would do `@existing.each {|r| r.update_attributes(...)}`. If you wanted to update a single record, you would need to do `Reklamer.find(:first, ...)` with conditions that ensured only the record that you desired to update would be matched.